# How is this an untable limit cycle?

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems, graphing-functions, bifurcation

I am investigating the Lorenz equations and in MATLAB I have plotted a case with $\sigma = 10, b = 8/3, r = 21$ and I have this phase portrait: [image]

However I am not exactly sure how this is an unstable limit cycle. According to Strogatz, this should be a saddle limit cycle. I am also unclear as to why there is that white space on the left cycle. Could someone please explain what is going on here? I think I am a bit lost when it comes to interpreting this plot.

Comment: As you did not provide any details of what you are doing except parameters, your picture is just a projection of a trajectory (or several ones). If you expect a system to have an attractor, you have to take a random initial condition, integrate it forward for a long time, erase first iterations and then picture what happened. If the result looks pretty much like a closed curve, you have a stable limit cycle. You can never detect a saddle cycle in this way.

Comment: I used MATLAB's ode45, with an initial condition of (10,10,6)

Comment: That is essentially what I did

Comment: Also, this doesn't really look like a limit cycle to me

Comment: There are two possiblities: 1) it is not a (stable) limit cycle, but a strange attractor or an attractive equilibria 2) if you erase an inital part of the trajectory, you will see the stable limit cycle

Comment: What do you mean by erase an initial part of the trajectory

Comment: Just do not plot the trajectory for the times from $[0,T]$, where $T$ is large but is (much) smaller than the overall (very large) integration time. Because it takes time for a trajectory to be attracted to something and you should wait until it comes really close to the limiting behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23906/discussion-between-curo-and-demitau).